# Create short Generic method

Tags: generics

I've created an interface where implementations should process commands and queries:

```
public interface IProcessor : IDisposable
{
    void Process<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand;
    TOutput Return<TQuery, TOutput>(TQuery query) where TQuery : IQuery;
}
```

The problem here is that I would like to have the IProcessor interface methods to be as short as possible when I use them.

```
public class WhateverController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IProcessor _processor;

    public WhateverController(IProcessor processor)
    {
        _processor = processor;
    }

    public List<Guid> Post(List<Whatever> whatevers)
    {
        var command = new CreateWhatever{ Whatevers = whatevers};
        _processor.Process(command);
        return command.Result;
    }

    public List<Whatever> Get()
    {
        var query = new GetAllWhatevers { };
        return _processor.Return(query);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _processor.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

I would like to have the IProcessor.Return(query) available to use and not IProcessor.Return so the shorter version...
I've already tried by creating an IQuery<TOutput> but I always have an error that there should be more type constraints...

Comment: Since the two methods require different number of generic type arguments you *can* name them the same, but if you want to rely on type inference when calling them you might end up having to specify the actual types, because the compiler can't deduce if you want the first or the second overload.

Comment: Correct, naming them the same works